# pandas RuntimeError in tseries/convertor when plotting

Tags: python, plot, pandas

When I execute the following statement:

```
DataFrame(randn(3,1),index=[date(2012,10,1),date(2012,9,1),date(2012,8,1)],columns=['test']).plot()
```

I get the following exception:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/converter.py", line 317, in **call**
    (estimate, dmin, dmax, self.MAXTICKS * 2))
RuntimeError: MillisecondLocator estimated to generate 5270400 ticks from 2012-08-01 00:00:00+00:00 to 2012-10-01 00:00:00+00:00: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS* 2 (2000)

Any workaround available for this bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to sort before plotting:

```
df.sort().plot()
```

*It looks like a bug, so I posted it on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2609)!*

Note: this seems to plot ticks better if you use datetime rather than date:

```
df1 = DataFrame(randn(3,1), index=[datetime(2012,10,1), datetime(2012,9,1), datetime(2012,8,1)], columns=['test'])
```