# matplotlib change Axis scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I have below plot my data is 2D array from range 0 to 10 but I want my plot's axis be between [0,1] how can I change the scale? 
besides how can I upside down Y axis?

```
mydata = np.zeros((10,10))
#fill mydata
im = plt.imshow(mydata,interpolation='bilinear', aspect='auto') 
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The extent parameter alters the ticks displayed on the imshow plot.
  The `extent` should be passed a 4-tuple or list with the following
  meaning: `extent=(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`.
- The `y-axis` can be inverted by passing `origin='lower'` to `imshow`.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mydata = np.random.random((10,10))

im = plt.imshow(mydata,interpolation='bilinear', aspect='auto',
                origin='lower', extent=[0, 1, 0, 1]) 
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Another way to invert the yaxis is to call `ax.invert_yaxis`. See [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16460828/190597) and [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8640615/190597) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

use plt.xticks(np.arange(5,50,5))